# Getting 403 When Trying to Connect to API. Using Angular, HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am learning how to connect to API's and am very new at this. I have been able to connect, and collect data from API's that are free and do not required authentication keys. But now I'm trying to connect to one that requires an authentication key, and I keep getting a 403 error, which as I understands means that I am not authorized to access the data.

The API I'm trying to access can be found here: https://rapidapi.com/theapiguy/api/thesportsdb/

Its url is: 'https://thesportsdb.p.rapidapi.com/searchplayers.php?t=Arsenal';

And it gives us the options requirements for (Node.js) Fetch as:

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'fbf....',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'thesportsdb.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};
```

So my service in angular looks like this:

```
  sportsUrl = 'https://thesportsdb.p.rapidapi.com/searchplayers.php'
  getData(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'fbf....',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'thesportsdb.p.rapidapi.com'
    })
    return this.http.get<any>(this.sportsUrl,{headers})
  }
```

I call this from my component with the following:

```
  fetchData(){
    this.sportsService.getData().subscribe({
        next: (data) => console.log(data),
        error: error => this.error = error,
      });
  }
```

When I try to subscribe, I get the 403 error.

I'm very new to using API's, I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) error code means you have no permission (authorization) to access this API. You need to check whether you have subscribed to API (issue on your RapidAPI subscription but not Angular)

Comment: I guess that was it. I read their instructions wrong. I thought you just needed an account, which gave me an access key. But I missed the part of having to actually subscribe to the service for that access key to work. Thanks again.

Comment: You must generate a new API key, you have published your secret in the question.